# How can I indent a selected paragraph in Pages on OS X?

Tags: macos, pages

This is very basic, but couldn't figure it out so far. If you select a paragraph on Microsoft World on Windows you can just press tab and the paragraph will move to the right. On the Mac, however, the whole text is replaced with the tab. In Xcode one can indent a block of text to the right by pressing <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> (or <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>) to unindent the selected text again. How can I do this in Pages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

⌘] and ⌘[ to increase and decrease indent level works in Pages too. These are the default shortcuts for the options available in Format → Text.

Comment: Aaargh I changed the language to German, because I had to write something German. This also changed these shortcuts to something awkward.